# Is it possible for superuser to create more than one post, and user to be post only one post?

Tags: django

currently, user can create only one post. but as a superuser I want to create more than one. I tried to do it in admin page but it won't work. Is there a way to do this?

```
@login_required
def add_category(request):
    if Category.objects.filter(author=request.user).exists():
        return render(request,'main/category_already_exists.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category(author=request.user)
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, instance=category)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        form = CategoryForm()

    return render(request, 'main/add_category.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@login_required
def add_category(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser and Category.objects.filter(author=request.user).exists():
         return render(request,'main/category_already_exists.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category(author=request.user)
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, instance=category)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
        return redirect('index')

else:
    form = CategoryForm()

return render(request, 'main/add_category.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: thank you but this doesn't work it says UNIQUE constraint failed: main_category.author_id probably because I have  author = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True)
in my model. sorry I didn't post this before

Comment: can you post your full model

Comment: Code blocks on their own aren't very useful, you should at least provide a small description stating what you've changed and *how* it solves the OP's problem

Comment: @Q-bart, all I have in my models.py author = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True)  and name field, any help?

Comment: I think, than OneToOne field does not require unique=True. It is unique, by default. Try to delete it..